# Debugging a console ChessEngine.exe "used" in another application (a chess GUI)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, console-application, chess

I have a `c++` console app project in visual studio 2019. Compiled, it gives a command line `engine.exe` that sends output after user input and command execution and waits for another user input etc.

In fact `engine.exe` is a chess engine that complies to the UCI interface standard, which among others forces the engine to be a command line executable and which allows to use the engine in the [Arena Chess GUI](http://www.playwitharena.de/), hence the `chess` tag. (The `c++` is because I coded the engine in `c++` inside visual studio and because I guess that the answer will depend on visual studio `c++` project settings.)

I can perfectely debug `Engine.exe` from the command prompt by inputing a first move, waiting for engines's response etc. You can do as you would debug the standard console hello world in visual studio, no problem.

Now I am much more interested to debug `Engine.exe` while *using* it from a chess GUI, namely [Arena Chess GUI](http://www.playwitharena.de/). But this does not work :

- In the properties of the project used to compile my engine I put (the path to) arena.exe in the command to execute when the debug is launched, and then, when debug is triggered and arena opened, I load in Arena a new engine corresponding to my engine, I put breakpoints in my code but each has a "no symbols loaded".
- I launch Arena, I load a new engine in it, the engine being the compiled debug version of my engine, and then in visual studio I make an "attach to process" and add Arena as process to attach to. Then the breakpoints in my code in visual studio have also "no symbols loaded".

I guess that the problem is that debugging a command line is impossible with visual studio outside of the windows cmd prompt, whereas you can debug a dll from any exe *using* it.

What is the standard way to proceed ?

*Remark.* I already posted my question on CSE here https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27911/debugging-my-chess-engine-through-the-arena-gui but finally think that it is more appropriate for SE as it formally does not depend on chess at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps you listed would work if your engine was a DLL loaded by that Arena.

However, your `engine.exe` will NOT be loaded by the Arena, but simply will get started with some unknown inter-process communication interface to pass information (moves) back and forth.

You have to attach the debugger to your engine, NOT to Arena.

Quick question: is your engine loaded just once on start or separately for each move?